# How to construct a tibble with nested data frame hardcoded way

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following 3 variables (1 string, and 2 data frames):

```r
library(tidyverse)


# Variable to use to construct tibble -------------------------------------

obsv_name <- "FOO"

dat1 <- structure(c(0.033, 0.066, 0.233, 
0.0333333333333333), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("CXX_4", 
"YXRPW_112"), c("A", "R")))

dat2 <- structure(c(0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.033), .Dim = c(2L, 2L
), .Dimnames = list(c("XXX_62", "YYY_208"), c("A", "R")))


obsv_name
#> [1] "FOO"
dat1
#>               A          R
#> CXX_4     0.033 0.23300000
#> YXRPW_112 0.066 0.03333333
dat2
#>           A     R
#> XXX_62  0.1 0.100
#> YYY_208 0.0 0.033
```

What I want to do is to construct a tibble with 3 column where the `dat1` and `dat2` need to be constructed as [nested data frame](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls13_list-columns.html#nested_data_frame,_modelling,_and_gapminder). How can I do that?

The final result will look like this:

```r
obsv_name  data_frame1              data_frame2
FOO        <list column of dat1>   <list column of dat2>
```

Comment: Try `tibble(obsv_name,  data_frame1= list(dat1), data_frame2 = list(dat2))`  Or it coud be `tibble(obsv_name,  data_frame1= list(as_tibble(dat1)), data_frame2 = list(as_tibble(dat2)))`

Comment: I would personally go with akrun's second suggestion. Nesting a tibble instead of a regular dataframe will enable you to use `unnest` operations on the nested list. For example: `df %>% unnest(data_frame1) %>% summarize(sum(A))`